# No module named Django:

Tags: python, django, apache2

I want to deploy my Django project in windows environment.I'm using:-

```
Windows7 64bit
Apache2
python2.7
Django 1.8
VCforPython
```

And after installing all required Dependencies

I have set my Environment Variables for:-

```
Variable name:PATH 
variable value:my python path
variable name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
variable value:project.settings
```

And my httpd.conf:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName http://localhost

        WSGIScriptAlias / C:\Apache2\htdocs\project\project\wsgi.py

        <Directory "C:\Apache2\htdocs\project">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But when i try to view my project in localhost/ i got "no module named Django"

What did miss??

Comment: How have you installed Django? What have you set your Python path to, and where have you made the setting?

Comment: @Antonis Christofides.. Install Django using Pip. My python path is C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;

What do you mean by where have i made the setting?

Comment: I believe you are confusing the python path with the shell path. You might want to read http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/ (disclosure:it's mine), which clears it up.

Answer (score -1):

Try following to make sure that django is picked from any of the path.

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Comment: I already try it and Django path exist. When i tried in Python shell with "import Django", there is no error..