# No Module Name django right after installing

Tags: python, django, windows, python-3.x, environment-variables

I'm trying to install django in a virtual environment on my Windows machine (I have python 3.6.4). I create the virtual environment and install django and get the success message. But when I try to see my django installation, I get the error below:
[image]
I'm seeing several similar questions on Stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926512/no-module-named-django) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862704/django-installation-error-no-module-named-django) but they are either on a different OS or have used a different means of installation and I've tried some of the suggestions with no luck. Does anyone know what is causing this and how to resolve?

Comment: you tried to check django on your original python (`c:/dev/python3.6/python.exe`). I guess that `py` is an alias and not referred to python from venv. Try to use full command `python -m django --version`

Comment: That was it! I knew it would be something obvious! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the process is straight forward:

```
# 1-running the windows powershell as administrator
# 2-installing the virtualenv
>>> pip install virtualenv
# 3-creating a virtualenv:
>>> virtualenv myenv
# 4-activating the virtualenv:
>>> cd myenv
>>> Scripts\activate
# installing django
>>> pip install django==1.11
# creating a django project:
>>> django-admin startproject my_project_name
```

if it doesn't work again :

- check the path to python3 on your windows machine
- checkout the [Documentation](http://pymote.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html)